# Oracle - Updating rows based on specific criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, datatable, procedure

Bellow is my Database schema:

table_A

```
row_Id  | ....
  1     |  ..
  2     |  ..
  3     |  ..
  4     |  ..
  ...
  ...
```

table_B

```
row_Id|table_A_row_Id|row_type
   1  |   1          |   A
   2  |   2          |   A
   3  |   2          |   A
   4  |   3          |   A
   5  |   3          |   A
   6  |   4          |   A
   7  |   4          |   B
   ...
   ...
```

table_C

```
row_Id|table_B_row_Id|row_type
   1  |   1          | foo
   2  |   1          | boo
   3  |   2          | foo
   4  |   3          | foo
   ...
   ...
```

table_B has one or two rows with type 'A' that belongs to one row in table_A. I need to change one 'A' to 'X' in all rows that have two 'A' if that row has 'foo' type in table_C, otherwise, if doesn't have 'foo' type in table_C, change first 'A' to 'X'. I hope I explained the problem well. Any suggestions about how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Nice exercice  ! But can you show the SQL you have tried ?

Comment: You didn't explain it well. "I need to change one 'A' to 'X' in all rows that have two 'A' **if that row** has... "  WHICH ROW? I am guessing the row from table A - except table_C does not seem to refer to rows from table_A. And in table_B you are talking about TWO rows, not one. Also, you said you must change "one of the 'A' to 'X' if *something*, and otherwise change the first 'A' to 'X'. What's the difference? WHICH 'A' should be changed to 'X' when "it" is 'foo' in table_C? And what do you mean by "first" anyway - first by row_Id of table B?

Comment: Posting the desired output from the given inputs as well as what you have tried would be minimum requirements before you can get meaningful help.

Comment: Basically, my idea was to loop through all rows in table_A and to select all from table_B that are in relation to current row in table_A. Than loop through all in table_B that (loop inside a loop) and to do a logic. 

foreach row in table_B 
if row has type A store it in some variable than another one.
if both variables contains something - check both with table_C
if first have foo, change it if not check another. something like that.
but I am not so good in writing queries. I can write some logic using Java language if that counts.

Comment: @mathguy If one row in table_B with type 'A'  - do nothing. If two rows in table_B with type 'A':

  a) If  both of them has ''foo'' in table_C change one no matter which one (first f.e).  

  b) If none has 'foo' - change first by row_Id and 
  c) if one has - change that one.

Comment: OK, so it seems table_A plays no role in this exercise; table_A_row_Id may reference table_A, but for this exercise that is irrelevant. Right?

Comment: @mathguy Yes. But my idea was to start looping from that one (table_A). I see that I was wrong.

Comment: @mathguy But notice that one or two rows with type 'A' are for the same row_Id in table_A.

Comment: OK - your requirement still doesn't make sense. For table_A_row_Id = 1 you have only one row in table_B, with row_Id = 1. But in table_C you have two rows for table_B_row_Id = 1, and with both foo and boo. So these would contradict each other. What's up with that?

Comment: @ThomasG

I would do something like this in Java:
List<B_row> list_with_A_type;

for(TableA A_row : A_rows) {
  for(TableB B_row : A_row.B_rows) {
     if (B_row.type == 'A') {
       list_with_A_type.add(B_row);
     }
  }
  if(list_with_A_type.size == 2) {
   
    if(list_with_A_type.get(0).hasFooInTable_C) {
      list_with_A_type.get(0).setType('X');
      break;
    } else {
       list_with_A_type.get(1).setType('X');
    }
  }
}

// missing part when none of them have 'foo' in table_C.

Comment: @mathguy If only one row with 'A' in table_B - do nothing like I said. Just change to 'X' if two rows.

Comment: But for this to work, you must guarantee that a table_B_row_Id appears only once in table_C, otherwise you will have contradictory specification for what to do. Done with this. Good luck!

Comment: @mathguy if table_B_row_Id does not appear in table_C - change first one by row_id. Or to make it easier - change whichever  'A' to 'X' per table_A_row_Id. No problem, thanks anyways.

Comment: The problem is not "does not appear". I already said it twice, this is the third time: the problem is if table_B row_ID appears in table_C MORE THAN ONCE, and with CONTRADICTORY row_type as you have for table_B_row_Id = 1. In that case there is only one row corresponding to table_A, so it doesn't matter, but if that happens for table_B_row_Id = 1 it may also happen for other values, and that's nonsense. Forget it!

Comment: @mathguy But even if  'table_B row_ID appears in table_C MORE THAN ONCE' just check if any of them has 'foo' (at least one 'foo' is needed) to change to 'X'. That is what I need; >1 'foo' change that, otherwise if 0 'foo' it does not matter which one will be changed to 'X' (one of two existing 'A');